# Group addon taking up too much space in bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add a `.group-addon` to an element inside a bootstrap `.table`, all other elements are not given enough space, and the group-addon input takes up far too much room.

```
<h2>Only one bully, group-addon</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">x</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>pushed around...</td>
            <td>being bullied...</td>
            <td>by group addons...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Two bullying group-addons</h2> 
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">x</div>
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">x</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>pushed around...</td>
            <td>being bullied...</td>
            <td>by group addons...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>No Bullies</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="cool" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>pushed around...</td>
            <td>being bullied...</td>
            <td>by group addons...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="alert alert-info">When there is no group-addon inside a table with class table, the spacing looks reasonable, but a single group-addon ruins it all</div>
```

[image: group-addon]

### http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/ntm2q/

How should I use group-addons inside bootstrap tables without them taking too much space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try in your Less / CSS:

```
.input-group-addon {
width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your bootstrap.min.css line 9 where you have this rules:

```
.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn {
width: 1%;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You should erase `width: 1%;` or just override with something like this:

```
.input-group-addon {
width:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ntm2q/1/)